# Chaining (pre appending) of JS functions that are defined with same signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have interface that defines validation function, it is defined in following way:

```
validate?: (
    rowData: RowData
  ) => { isValid: boolean; helperText?: string } | string | boolean;
```

Until now I was always assigning one function, like this:

```
interface ValidationType {
    isValid: boolean
    helperText: string
}

const validateFunction = (data: Data): ValidationType | true => {...}

{...,
    validate = data => validateFunction(data)
}
```

But now, one step later (after intitial assignment of validate function), I want to expend it and add one more default function that should trigger before one that was passed, something like this:

```
const defaultValidation = (data: Data): ValidationType | true => {
    return true
}

something.validate = defaultValidation + something.validate
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting following error: `Operator '+' cannot be applied to types ...`

I don't know how to tackle this in most precise way that follows OOP, should I try reassigning validate with new anonymous function that is going to call both inside of it, something like this?

```
columns[i].validate = (data: Data): ValidationType | true => {
                    const defaultValidationResponse = defaultValidation(data);
                    if(defaultValidationResponse !== true) return defaultValidationResponse;
                    const answer = columns[i].validate?.(data) || true
                    if (answer === true) {
                        return true
                    }
                    return answer as ValidationType 
                }
```

Is this even going to always work? I don't know how to approach the problem because I don't know what's the correct way of thinking about it (what's most precise regarding OOP patterns).

Comment: So to clarify what you're asking, you want a default handler that ALWAYS runs before any provided handlers?

Comment: @Kwright02 Exactly

Comment: Are your validators stored in an object somewhere? Basically, where is your array of validators kept, and when do you run them?

Comment: Default validator is always the same, custom validator can be any function that is passed.
I need a solution to prepend execution of default validator before the custom one.

Comment: I understand, we've established that already. But where are you running them from? Are the validators appended to an object property like Object.validators?